# scrape links from website nested in websites with R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I would like to ask for help with creating list of links which I need to download several documents.

I am trying to download delimation of electoral districts in the Czech Republic. It is available on website http://data.cuzk.cz/kontroly-dat-isui/00-volebni-okrsky/CSV-2014-10-01/. However, the tables are provided in hierarchical structure(regions - counties - districts) and it is about 2 000 tables, therefore it is hard to dowload them manually.

I have already found how to collect links in each website in hierarchy, but it would be perfect to find out how to write a code which applies to all webpages on the certain level.

```
#"scrape" links for regions
url <- "http://data.cuzk.cz/kontroly-dat-isui/00-volebni-okrsky/CSV-2014-10-01/"
webpage<-  getURL(url,encoding="UTF-8")
PARSED <- htmlParse(webpage)
regions <- xpathSApply(PARSED, "//a", xmlValue)
links <-paste(url, regions, "/", sep="")

#"scrape" links for the counties in the first region (but I need to download links also in all other regions)
url_county <- "http://data.cuzk.cz/kontroly-dat-isui/00-volebni-okrsky/CSV-2014-10-01/Jihocesky_kraj/"
webpage_county <-  getURL(url_county,encoding="UTF-8")
PARSED_county <- htmlParse(webpage_county)
county <- xpathSApply(PARSED_county, "//a", xmlValue)
links_counties <-paste(url, county, "/", sep="")

#and finally links for the districts in the county (but I need to download links also in all other counties in all other regions)
url_district <- "http://data.cuzk.cz/kontroly-dat-isui/00-volebni-okrsky/CSV-2014-10-01/Jihocesky_kraj/Ceske_Budejovice/"
webpage_district <-  getURL(url_district,encoding="UTF-8")
PARSED_district <- htmlParse(webpage_district)
district <- xpathSApply(PARSED_district, "//a", xmlValue)
links_districts <-paste(url, district,  sep="")
```

I try to use loop, but it does not work.

```
for(i in 1:length(links)){
webpage_county <-  getURL(links[i],encoding="UTF-8")
PARSED_county  <- htmlParse(webpage_county)
links_counties <- xpathSApply(PARSED_county , "//a", xmlValue)
}
```

Does anybody body have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: Only a guess, but you probably want an index on the output variable, eg `links_counties[[i]] <- ...` otherwise it's just overwriting it each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it does not work. It replies this warning message<br/>
     `Error in links_county[[i]] <- paste(url, county, "/", sep = "") : 
  object 'links_county' not found`<br/>The resulting object probably cannot be indexed, because line `links_county <- paste(url, county, "/", sep = "")` is without a problem